# error message for typo in variables

Tags: r

Is there a way to force R to reject a wrong variable name instead just run it successfully without any error message? For example:

```
Mydata$ABC <- "1"
    Mydata$ABC[Mydata$Gedner == "F"] <- "0"
```

This is just an example (the variable name should be `Gender`), an error like this sure is easy to spot manually, but when I made a typo in 500 line of codes with numerous comparisons like:

```
Mydata$ABC[Mydata$Gedner == "F" & Mydata$A < 1 & Mydata$B>1 & (etc)] <- "0"
```

it become almost impossible to spot the error quickly. Not to mention I put `l` instead of `I` in the bug I just noted. It took me 2 days to figure it out.

I know this is stupid and there should be quicker way to spot...Any suggestion?

Comment: `Mydata$ABC[Mydata[, "Gedner"] == "F"] <- "0"`

Comment: @mark999, This does make sense! Just that the code will look extremely bulky as I am making many comparisons... Would there be any other way to do that?

Comment: @Tim, I am not sure what is consider as off topic here. sorry about that. But my code did run without any error.... I don't know why yours can generate error...

Comment: @oce Check: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I actually found this when I was googling solution, so I thought this is a similiar questions... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103074/how-to-organise-the-variable-names-in-r-without-messing-up

Comment: @ Tim, I know why yours have error. I have already created the variable abc, so if you run: `mtcars$abc <- 0`

`mtcars$abc[mtcars$cly > 0 ] <- 0` it will have no error. Thanks!

Comment: @oce I don't know of any other way. But it also has the benefit that you can do `Mydata[, v]` with `v` being a character variable, and you can also do, for example, `Mydata[, paste(v1, v2, sep="")]`.

Comment: @mark999, sorry I don't understand... I tried but it just give error messages... can you explain how paste is use here? I really would like to learn about this.

Comment: `d <- data.frame(ab = 0:9, ac = 1:10); v1 <- "a"; v2 <- "b"; d[, paste(v1, v2, sep="")]`

Comment: @mark999, oh I see what you mean! This is really useful for some of my variable with different timepoint! Great thanks!